# What is the maximum number of columns and size for Azure Sql Data warehouse table record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, data-warehouse

I am looking to denormalize many tables into one table in Azure Sql Data warehouse which would require large number of fields (~1500 columns).  Does anyone know the limitation of the number of columns for a PDW table and the maximum row size?

Also what is this best practice in the sense of performance and maintainability?  To create one huge table or break it apart into multiple one to one relationship tables.

Comment: `Also what is this best practice in the sense of performance and maintainability? `  Not making 1500 columns in a single table.  Split the data up into multiple relational tables...  That's kinda the point of a database, and what it's optimised to handle.

Comment: The max number of columns is WAY more than any rationale system would even pretend to get close to. How do you anticipate a column with 1500 columns is going to be manageable? Don't do this to yourself.

Comment: The source of the data is from normalized relational tables (~50 tables).  Denormalization would make it easy on the end user to query and also gain much performance improvements.  Maintenance is not so much an issue unless there are limitations (like max # of cols).

Comment: How much data are you looking to store? And what are your query patterns? If you are looking to query over de-normalized data - DocumentDB may be worth taking a look at. I'd like to learn more about your scenario - pls ping me: andrl {at} microsoft.com

Answer (score 1):

The number of columns in a regular Azure SQL Database table is restricted to 1024 (similar to the on-premises SQL Server). With sparse columns, a table can have up to 30,000 columns, of which up to 1023 can be non-sparse. However, at least 28,976 have to be sparse columns. One non-sparse column is used for the column set that is mandatory if the total number of columns is greater than 1024.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj553018.aspx