# Create & Insert data with schema of Dataframe

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, azure-sql-database

I have a csv that has 3300 attributes/columns. I cannot afford to create the columns manually in AZ SQL DB. I am looking out ways to automatically do it using Python. Came across to_sql and SQL Alchemy but does not look like it is working.

> Error; ArgumentError: Expected string or URL object, got <pyodbc.Connection object at 0x0000022429404440>

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import urllib
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
fpath = r"C:\Users\***\test.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(fpath)
#print(df.head(5))


conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:XXX.database.windows.net,1433;DATABASE=XXX;UID=XXX;PWD=XXX")#;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;")
engine = create_engine(conn)
df.to_sql(name='test',con=engine, if_exists='append',index=False)
```

Comment: Could you please provide the error if you are getting anything?

Comment: The CSV file has 3,300 columns? You're going to need to do something *before* it gets to SQL Server then. Per the [capacity specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) a table can't have more than 1,024 columns (unless it's [sparse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-column-sets?view=sql-server-ver16) and then it's up to 30,000), and the row size can't be more than 8,060 bytes (excluding row-overflow storage). Sounds like the file is heavily denormalised.

Comment: If you do have that many columns, perhaps you should consider normalising what you can, and then inserting the rest as something like XML or JSON.

Comment: @ThomA Good point on the table size restriction. I will have to think on it.

Comment: Any idea if the column size is not a constraint? Lets say I have 700 columns.

Comment: Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655845/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-columns-and-size-for-azure-sql-data-warehouse-tabl) once?

Answer (score -2):

you can use SQLAlchemy, it will automatically create the SQL table and insert all information. If the table already exists, it will only insert the data. I hope this helps.

```
# Create the MySQL connection string
connection_string = f"mysql+pymysql://{mysql_connection_params['user']}:{mysql_connection_params['password']}@{mysql_connection_params['host']}:{mysql_connection_params['port']}/{mysql_connection_params['database']}"

# Create a SQLAlchemy engine
engine = create_engine(connection_string)

# Insert data into the table using pandas to_sql method
with engine.connect() as connection:
    # Specify the connection and use the 'append' method to insert data
    df.to_sql(name=table_name, con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=500)  # Adjust chunksize as needed
```

Comment: I have an Azure SQL DB. Does the above still would work?

Comment: Why are you using a MySQL connector here..?

Comment: A question should be answered with a solution not a suggestion unless they ask for a suggestion.